# C# operation overflows trying to assign a valid value to double

Tags: c#, double, overflow

I am trying to get the number of bytes in a terabyte. If I use the Pow function, I am alright, but when I explicitly try to multiply 1024 four times, I get an error.

```
  Console.WriteLine((double.MaxValue)); // 1.79769313486232E+308
  Console.WriteLine(Math.Pow(1024, 4)); // Clearly, 1099511627776 < MaxValue
  double d2 = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024; // error
```

error CS0220: The operation overflows at compile time in checked mode

Why is this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
double d2 = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
```

> The operation overflows at compile time in checked mode

Because you are creating an integer 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024, which overflows int.MaxValue, and *then* assigning it to a double.

```
double d2 = 1024.0 * 1024.0 * 1024.0 * 1024.0;
```

should work fine.

Comment: It's not necessarily obvious.

Comment: you can use `1024D` as well, might make intent more obvious